# How to get the iteration number of lsqnonlin

Tags: matlab, estimation

I am doing parameter estimation in matlab using lsqnonlin function.

In my work, I need to plot a graph to show the error in terms of lsqnonlin iteration. So, I need to know which iteration is running at each point of time in lsqnonlin. Could anybody help me how I can extract the iteration number while lsqnonlin is running?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass it an options parameter setting `'display'` to either `'iter'` or `'iter-detailed'`

http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#f265106

Comment: This option is not yet documented in `2012b`. Hopefully the functionality is already there, but if not my answer can perhaps still be of use.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin you've always been able to set the display to show you information at each iteration. It looks like they might have changed it slightly, I used to do it using optimset: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimset.html

Answer (score 1):

Never used it myself, but looking at the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) of `lsqnonlin`, it seems that there is an option to set a custom [output function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#f11022), which gets called during every iteration of the solver. Looking at the [specification](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html), it seems that the values `optimValues.iteration` and `optimValues.fval` get passed into the function, which is probably the things you are interested in.

You should thus define your own function with the right signature, and depending on your wishes, this function prints it on the command line, makes a plot, saves the intermediate results in a vector, etc. Finally, you need to pass this function as a function handle to the solver: `lsqnonlin(..., 'OutputFcn', @your_outputfun)`.

Comment: +1 Every so often an outputfcn is needed, though rarely in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this would be:

1. Start with a low number of (maximum) iterations
2. Get the result
3. Increase the number of iterations
4. Get the result
5. If the maximum iterations is used Go to step 3

This is what I would recommend in most cases when performance is not a big issue.

However, if you cannot afford to do it like this, try `edit lsqnonlin` and go digging untill you find the point where the number of iterations is found. Then change the function to make sure you store the results you need at that point. (don't forget to change it back afterwards).

The good news is that all relevant files seem to be editable, the bad news is that it is not so clear where you can find the current number of iterations. A quick search led me to `fminbnd`, but I did not manage to confirm that this is actually used by `lsqnonlin`.